# Get User ID from a kunena profile

Tags: profile, kunena

I am trying to get a user id from a users **Kunena** profile to be able to open a new **uddeIM** letter with their name already inserted within the message username.

So far I have tried many things but the closest I have gotten is the following:

```
public function getInboxURL ($userid)
{
    static $itemid = false;

    if ($itemid === false)
    {
        $itemid = 0;

        if (method_exists($this->uddeim, 'getItemid'))
        {
            $itemid = $this->uddeim->getItemid();
        }

        if ($itemid)
        {
            $itemid = '&Itemid=' . (int) $itemid;
        }
        else
        {
            $itemid = '';
        }
    }

    return JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_uddeim&task=new&recip=' . (JFactory::getUser()->id));
}
```

The only problem is this opens a new letter with MY username as the user.

Please, can someone help?

Comment: I haven't seen the whole setup of how you arrive at this function completely, but the userid appears passed into it. Try using: $userid instead of jfactory get user.

Comment: Kunena developer said to use $this->profile->userid; but i have tried to throw that in everywhere from the parameter to the return and even in the class.. The whole code is posted here on kunenas forum http://www.kunena.org/forum/k-4-0-general-questions/135253-getuserid-from-a-kunena-profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok kunena developer has a hotfix for this uploaded now on github for the next upcomming update release, here is the commit link. https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/pull/3547